# Samsung SSD Firmware Update Power Cycle on MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, power, firmware

I am trying to install the firmware update for my Samsung 840 Series (250GB) on my MacBook Pro 13" (early 2011). As explained in Samsung's [installation guide](http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/downloads/software/Samsung_SSD_Firmware_Update_Utility_User_Manual_English_for_Mac_v10.pdf) I downloaded the respective [.iso file](http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools.html) and created a bootable DVD.

Just before I wanted to reboot from the DVD I read in the installation guide that for some systems the firmware update utility will ask you to power cycle the drive meaning that you have to **disconnect the SSD from the SATA and power cable for a short moment.**

So I guess, the only way to install this firmware update is by removing the SSD and putting it into some SSD enclosure which will be connected to my MBP, right? Is there really no way to update while still having the SSD inside my MBP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The back cover of the MacBook Pro **does not** need to be on in order to operate.  You can even have the drive brackets removed.  Simply use a piece of non-conductive tape (I've used blue painters tape) to temporarily hold the drive in place.  I've also found that this works best at the edge of a desk or table with a towel or large mousepad for the MBP to rest on when I have it inverted.

If you are required to power cycle the drive, carefully turn over your MBP ensuring you don't close the lid,  pull the drive up, disconnect and reconnect the drive's SATA connector.  This will power the cycle the SSD.

Once that's done, you can turn the MBP back over and continue the process.

Comment: Thanks Allan, thats very helpful! If I power cycle the SSD the way you described it will all data on it be lost, i.e. do I have to reinstall OS X?

Comment: Doing the firmware update could wipe it as well.  I've "never* lost data doing that...but I wouldn't risk it.  Do a backup!

Comment: No worries.  The trick to most of this stuff is have a backup in multiple places because no matter how good a tech is, even the best of us (Steve Jobs included) messes up.  I've done so many time on very colossal scales - backups saved me every time.